# How to check if a dict has a specific key?

Tags: vimscript

In Vimscript, how can one check whether the dictionary `my_dict` has the key `abc`?
Something like this:

```
echo 'abc' in my_dict
" The above naive approach gives "E121: Undefined variable: in"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `has_key` function:

```
has_key(my_dict, 'abc')
```

This will return 1 if the key is found, and 0 if the key is not found.

Comment: one can also use `get(my_dict, 'abc', 'default_value_if_key_is_not_there')`